# Is it Ok to make a POST endpoint to create an entry in a database idempotent?

Tags: api, rest

I have an endpoint that inserts a stock ticker into a table in a DB. I personally don't care if this endpoint gets hit with a ticker that already exists in the DB. I'd like to just return a 201 no matter what. If it doesn't exists, it gets created. If it does exist, just no op and tell the user it was created.

I feel like this is Ok because it's just a simple lookup table that is being controlled internally. If I had others consuming the API that were trying to create their own stock tickers in an app then that's a scenario when I don't want it to be idempotent and alert the user.

Does this break REST standard though? Should a POST, used in this context, not be idempotent? What are potential downsides to doing this?

Comment: https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post

Comment: How do you identify this `stock ticker`? How do you determine whether it already exists or not? Maybe you could add a simplified example if your data & API URLs/URIs?

Comment: All tickers are unique so that's the primary key in the table. If the table has a key collision and throws an exception on insert I just swallow the exception. The alternative would be checking for the value in the db before attempting to insert.